# Access is telling me one of my fields isn't part of an aggregate function, but that doesn't seem to be true

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

So I'm trying to run a query and I'm getting the fairly common error:

```
"You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'X' as part of an aggregate function"
```

, where X is the field that isn't part of an aggregate function. Normally it's a pretty straightforward error, however in my situation, there is no field specified, the error just reads:

```
"...specified expression '' as part of an..."
```

I've tried to searching and can't find any other cases of this happening. The biggest thing that stumps me about this is that I was working on an example case of the exact query to try and re-create the error and while the syntax is nearly identical, the example case works perfectly fine. I've tried just copying and pasting the example case into the real file and substituting the example field names with the real ones and it's still giving me an error. I'm seriously baffled. Here is the actual SQL:

```
SELECT 

qry_merge2_v2.Concatenate2, 
IIf((([Second Date? (dd/mm/yyyy)] & qry_merge2_v2.Concatenate2) In (SELECT qry_concatenate_dictionary.Concatenate FROM qry_concatenate_dictionary)),1,0) AS [Counter]

FROM qry_merge2_v2

GROUP BY qry_merge2_v2.Concatenate2, qry_merge2_v2.Period;
```

And here is the example code that I made to try and duplicate the error which actually produces no errors when it runs in its own file:

```
SELECT 

qry_datenamerate.sName AS MerchantName, 
IIf((([Second Date? (dd/mm/yyyy)] & qry_datenamerate.sName) In (SELECT qry_namedateconcat.Concat FROM qry_namedateconcat)),1,0) AS [Counter]

FROM qry_datenamerate

GROUP BY qry_datenamerate.sName, qry_datenamerate.sDate;
```

Comment: All I can suggest is to try to simplify it even more and see if the problem goes away at some point. For example, put constants (like, `'a' AS Concatenate2, 1 AS Counter`) and see if the error goes away. If it does, slowly reconstruct it until you've isolated which part it doesn't like. Also, if the `qry_` objects are in fact queries, run them separately to make sure they are doing what you expect.

Comment: First of all thanks for the response! I ended up trying to remove the middle SELECT statement after the IN, adding in a "Concatenate2" column manually and referring to that, and now it seems to work. It doesn't do exactly what I need it to, but I think I can probably modify it to do what it needs. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: In your original query expression, you have two fields selected: Concatenate2 and Counter. The second one needs some kind of aggregate function applied such as first, last, etc. or a group by statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an appropriate aggregate function for your second query field:

```
SELECT 

qry_merge2_v2.Concatenate2, 
SUM(IIf((([Second Date? (dd/mm/yyyy)] & qry_merge2_v2.Concatenate2) In (SELECT qry_concatenate_dictionary.Concatenate FROM qry_concatenate_dictionary)),1,0)) AS [Counter]

FROM qry_merge2_v2

GROUP BY qry_merge2_v2.Concatenate2, qry_merge2_v2.Period;
```